# How can I fetch the client IPv4 address in Go?

Tags: go

I am trying to write a function that returns the client IPv4 address.

I fetch the string from `http.Request.RemoteAddr` and filter out the ip with `net.SplitHostPort`. This gives me ::1 because I am on localhost which I asume is supposed to be an IPv6 address?

then I do `ip := net.ParseIP(s)` and then `ip = ip.To4()` to get the IPv4 address.

I am on Windows and have this in my hosts file: (The rest is commented out.)

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.com www.localhost.com *.localhost.com
```

Basically I expect to get 127.0.0.1, but I can't get it.

This is the code:

```
func FilterIpv4(r *http.Request) (string, error) {
    var s string
    // if xff := r.Header.Get("X-Forwarded-For"); xff != "" {
    //  ip = xff
    // }
    s, _, err := net.SplitHostPort(r.RemoteAddr)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    ip := net.ParseIP(s)
    ip = ip.To4()
    spew.Dump(ip.String()) // outputs "<nil>"
    return "", nil

}
```

EDIT:

I don't know if it is a good idea to do this but atleast I get the ipv4 addresses now. Maybe I should just stick to ipv6? I don't know about this. But replacing this code:

```
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":"+config.SrvPort, router))
```

With this:

```
ln, err := net.Listen("tcp4", ":"+config.SrvPort)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
log.Fatal(http.Serve(ln, router))
```

Made it possible for me to get the ipv4 address.

Does someone know if this is a good idea in general? Or should I stick to ipv6 addresses?

EDIT 2:

I ended up with this function:

```
func FilterIP(r *http.Request) (string, error) {
    var ip string
    var err error
    if xff := r.Header.Get("X-Forwarded-For"); xff != "" {
        ips := strings.Split(xff, ", ")
        ip = ips[0]
    } else {
        ip, _, err = net.SplitHostPort(r.RemoteAddr)
        if err != nil {
            return "", err
        }
    }
    if !IsIP(ip) {
        return "", err
    }
    return ip, nil
}
```

I will save both ipv6 and ipv4 addresses.

Comment: I think you have a misconception about IP addresses. You can't just convert IPv6 to IPv4 Addresses.

Comment: Yeah probably I am thinking in the wrong way.

Comment: Listening only for IPv4 is a way, but I don't recommend it as it's not future-proof. By the way, what problem tries `FilterIpv4` to solve?

Comment: It tries to check if the ip is a valid one, and also check if the client is behind a proxy. I wanted to get ipv4 to begin with because that is what I am used to from "php days", but I don't know, maybe I should just stick to ipv6?

Comment: If a client connects with IPv6 it doesn't have an IPv4 address and vice versa. Neither is more or less valid, it just the network protocol used.